# failed to compile, Syntax error: Missing semicolon

Tags: reactjs

Im making a sidebar and want to use some data from json format, so i make this code and dont know where did i wrong.

Here is my Code :

```
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { API_URL } from '../utils/constant';
    
    const Sidebar = ({show}) => {
        constructor(props) { //here is where i got wrong
            super(props)
        
            this.state = {
                 game:[]
            }
        }
        
        componentDidMount() {
            axios
              .get(API_URL + "game")
              .then(res => {
                const game = res.data;
                this.setState({ game });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("error lul", error);
              })
          }
    
          console.log("game : ", this.state.game);
```

btw, this list is for the pop-up side bar that i previously used, and i still put this on same file

```
          return (
                <div className={show ? 'sidenav active' : 'sidenav'}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#home'>Dota</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#home'>Counter Strike</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#home'>Valorant</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                
            </div>
        )
    }

export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem which I can find is that you are using `componentDidMount()`, `constructor()` in a functional component instead of a class component. Either convert your functional component to a class component or vice versa. If you convert to [class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) then you have to extend `Component` and add a `render()` method. If you convert to functional component then you have to use [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: i'm actually change my code, and it worked. but the sidebar pop up didnt show like before, what should i do to make it showed again? im changing const sidebar to this code : return ({ show }) => {

Comment: please provide any link of your updated code

Comment: maybe from github, https://github.com/dannyambarita/Tubes_PWL/blob/main/webgame-app/src/components/Sidebar.js

Comment: your `render()` method is wrong. I believe you are getting `show` as a prop. Check this [link](https://pastebin.com/YyWADQ1T) I created.